# How to bind to a window's command?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a dependency property on a user control called "RefreshCommand" (ICommand type) that I want to bind to a Command in my main window.

If I write this in code, it works...

```
MainToolbar.RefreshCommand = (ICommand)this.CommandBindings[0].Command;
```

.. but how can I express that in XAML?

I would additionally like to refer to the command by its name as opposed to its index.

Thanks,

Comment: A couple of things. 1 - how are you certain that the command you are looking for is always going to be the first command in the list?  2 - What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: 1) thats the thing, I really need a way to refer to it by name. 2) What I am trying to achieve is a way to share commands between my main window and user controls. So I have a property on my user control that I want to bind the main windows property into.

Answer (score 1):

you can bind in XAML to other XAML Element through e.g.

- The Element name:

`RefreshCommand="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=CommandBindings[0].Command}"`

- On Properties of "yourself"

`RefreshCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},                       Path=CommandBindings[0].Command}"`

- Upwards along the tree with AncestorType

`RefreshCommand="{Binding Path=CommandBindings[0].Command, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"`

If the toolbar is a child from window, I suppose the third should work well.

Comment: Should have specified - is there a way to access the command by its name?

Comment: I haven't tried, but can you specify the command bindings in XAML and give them a name to be referred to with elementname?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing this then.

3 Classes

```
MainWindow.xaml (Window)
MainViewModel.cs (Class)
UserControl.xaml (UserControl)
```

Set the data context of the MainWindow to the ViewModel.  The UserControl will inheret this data context unless you change it explicitly.  Set up the controls on the user control / main window to bind to relay commands on the Main View Model.

This will give you the context you need without hard coding indexes (xxx.[0]) and still maintain a degree of separation.